# What is the best way to send variable via getJSON to database query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, json

I have the following code... and I am trying to pass in a parameter to replace "id = 0", with a value.  Is there a way to do that, or a better way to do it?

DB Call

```
include 'db.php';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable where id = 0;");
```

JSON call:

```
$(function(){
    var items="";
    $.getJSON("mypage.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) {
        items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.title+"</option>";
        });
        // .... some stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse variables throw your getJSON request.

Do the following:

```
$.getJSON("mypage.php", {id : 2}, function(data){
    // .... some stuff
});
```

Php receives the variable via GET:

```
include 'db.php';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

$id = $_GET["id"]; 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable where id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($id).";");
```

Make sure that you use mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent mysql injections...

Comment: Awesome - this helped out quite a bit!